# Como se comporta o Pickle com variáveis armazenadas? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo Python por conta própria e agora estou praticando o módulo Pickle. Consegui fazer ele funcionar normalmente, mas me ocorreu uma dúvida sobre o que acontece quando eu 'armazeno uma variável no pote de picles'.

Digamos que estou tentando armazenar informações sobre uma pessoa. Para isso, escrevi dois arquivos separados. No primeiro, crio a função de Salvar e Carregar e no outro armazeno a classe "Pessoa" e um exemplo.

## Arquivo 1 (Var.py)

```py
import pickle

class Pessoa(self, Nome, Sobrenome, Idade):
    self.Nome = Nome
    self.Sobrenome = Sobrenome
    self.Idade = Idade

Fulano = Pessoa('', '', '')
```

## Arquivo 2 (Arm.py)

```py
import pickle
import Var

# Função de Armazenar #
def Armazenar():
    Sujeito = open('Sujeito.pck', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(Var.Fulano, Sujeito)
    Sujeito.close()


# Função de Carregar #
def Carregar():
    Sujeito = open('Progress.pck', 'rb')
    Var.Fulano = pickle.load(Sujeito)
    Sujeito.close()

# Programa Principal #

# Primeiro carregamos o último sujeito armazenado #
Carregar() 

# Depois imprimimos para ver se era esse mesmo #
print('Sujeito anterior:')
print('Nome: {}'.format(Var.Fulano.Nome))
print('Idade: {}'.format(Var.Fulano.Sobrenome))
print('Nome: {}'.format(Var.Fulano.Idade))

# Agora inserimos um novo sujeito #
print('Vamos definir um novo sujeito!')
Var.Fulano.Nome = input('Insira o nome: ')
Var.Fulano.Nome = input('Insira o sobrenome: ')
Var.Fulano.Nome = input('Insira a idade: ')

# Salvamos o sujeito #
Salvar()

# Essa parte foi só uma 'prova real' que eu inventei #
# Como teste, eu redefino Fulano e dou carregar #
# Se aparecer o que eu armazenei ao invés da mensagem de erro, deu certo! #
print('Vamos definir um novo sujeito!')
Var.Fulano.Nome = ('Se isso aparecer, deu errado.')
Var.Fulano.Nome = ('Se isso aparecer, deu errado.')
Var.Fulano.Nome = ('Se isso aparecer, deu errado.')

# Carregamos o novo sujeito #
Carregar()

# Imprimimos o novo sujeito #
print('Sujeito anterior:')
print('Nome: {}'.format(Var.Fulano.Nome))
print('Idade: {}'.format(Var.Fulano.Sobrenome))
print('Nome: {}'.format(Var.Fulano.Idade))
```

Não tive problema nenhum com esse código. Ele funcionou certinho como eu esperava, mas daí fiquei pensando no arquivo que o módulo Pickle cria para armazenar o sujeito (neste caso, o arquivo 'Sujeito.pck') e o que acontece com as informações armazenadas, porque, dependendo, talvez esse código me dê problemas mais pra frente conforme eu vou armazenando novos 'Fulanos'.

Quero dizer, quando eu salvo a Pessoa Fulano (dou o pickle.dump) e depois salvo a Pessoa Fulano novamente (dou outro pickle.dump) com novas informações, o que acontece? O anterior continua armazenado ali? Ele é substituído? Se ficar fazendo isso continuamente os Fulanos vão entupir o arquivo 'Sujeito.pck' e ele vai ficar enorme? Como gerencio isso?

Se alguém souber e puder me explicar, agradeço imensamente!